# Enter compound statements interactivly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble running this simple statement in the IDLE prompt.

```
if True:
    print("True") # need to press ENTER twice?
else:
  print("False")  # need to press ENTER twice?
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using Python 2 or 3? It looks ok for 2; would need to use `print()` in 3.

Comment: Oh, and your indentation is inconsistent.

Comment: It is Python3. Fixed and Re-tagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDLE is automatically indenting when you press return.  Press delete to remove the automatic indentation.

```
if True:
    print("True") # press return, then backspace
else:
    print("False")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. Must wait 5 min to accept and can't vote since my quota is over :)